# Team System 2008 comnnand unable to find workspace

Tags: tfs

I am trying to rename a folder in Team System 2008 Source Control to remove a space character:

```
tf rename "$/Common Controls" $/CommonControls
```

but I get the error 'unable to determine the workspace'. There doesn't seem to be a way of specifying the workspace. I get the same error if I try to move a folder using the same approach.

What am I doing wrong (or not doing)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the files locally to do the move or rename. It is not possible to do this server side only.

Create a local workspace, get all the files, then perform the rename within the context of the workspace.

NOTE: You cant rename a root folder. This is linked to the Team Project and neither can be renamed.

Comment: What then is the point of the "tf rename" command (if it can't be used to rename a folder)? Have I missed something?